# Adding Space Between Posts in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

New WP user here. I've installed WP on my website and created a couple of test posts. I noticed that there wasn't any space in between them.

I searched on Google and the solution seems to be to modify the .post deceleration in the style.css file. I'm running WP 3.3.2 and cannot seem to find the declaration. A solution from 2 years ago says its on line 262?

I cannot seem to find the declaration. Could anyone help me out?

Here is the link to my blog: www.clementma.ca/blog

Thanks,
Clement

Answer (score 0):

File responsible for creating posts on main page is `content.php` under your active theme( I am assuming as twentyeleven) . Whole post is generated from this line of code-

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
.......
.......
</article>
```

Let me know if you once you fixed it.